# How to group certain symbolic expressions?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

For example, I have the following expression :

```
A( 2 x1 + B(y1 + y2) + 2 x2 )
```

How do I make the output look like this (grouping `(x1 + x2)` and `(y1 + y2)` terms together) ?

```
2A (x1 + x2) + A B (y1 + y2)
```

I don't know why `Simplify` doesn't group `(x1 + x2)` together but just gives:

```
A (2 x1 + 2 x2 + B (y1 + y2))
```

I can use `Collect` to get `(y1 + y2)` after `Simplify` but how about `(x1 + x2)` ?

Remember this is just a simple example, I would have a much more complicated terms involving `(x1 + x2)` and `(y1 + y2)`, so a method with no operation on the constants (`2A` and `A B`) would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps replacing with dummies for simplification?

```
doThat[expr_, vars_List] := 
 Expand[Simplify[
    expr /. Flatten[
      Solve[# == ToString@#, First@Variables@#] & /@ vars]], 
   Alternatives @@ ToString /@ vars] /. 
  Thread[ToString /@ vars -> vars]
```

So

```
doThat[c a (x1 + x2) + d a (x1 + x2) + a (y1 + y2), {x1 + x2, 
  y1 + y2}]
```

gives

> a (c + d) (x1 + x2) + a (y1 + y2)

Comment: Thanks, this can take care of the minus sign if any.

Comment: @FredG haha. What about the edited code?

Answer (score 8):

One can apply a proper function as the third argument of `Collect`:

From documentation :

> ```
> Collect[expr,var,h]  applies h to the expression that forms the coefficient of each term 
> obtained.
> ```

Here we can use `B` as `var` and `Factor` as `h` :

```
Collect[ A( 2x1 + B(y1 + y2) + 2x2), B, Factor]
```

> ```
> 2 A (x1 + x2) + A B (y1 + y2)
> ```

Instead of `Factor` one can use here `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`, and `{B, A}` instead of `B`.  In full generality we cannot say what is the most appropriate function, it depends rather on a case-by-case basis. Sometimes one can get expected forms using only appropriate options in `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` like : `ComplexityFunction`, `ExcludedForms`, `TransformationFunctions`.  More can be found in tutorials e.g. [Simplification](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Simplification.html) or `Simplification Control` in [Algebraic Transformations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/AlgebraicTransformations.html)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will get you started :

```
expr = A*(2*x1 + B*(y1 + y2) + 2*x2) ;

rules = {c_ x1 + c_ x2 -> c (x1 + x2), d_ y1 + d_ y2 -> d (y1 + y2)} ;

(expr // Expand) //. rules 

(* 2 A (x1 + x2) + A B (y1 + y2) *)
```

Comment: BTW, how do you make a pattern for {c_ x1 - c_ x2 -> c (x1 - x2)} ? It won't recognize the minus sign.

Comment: In the simple cases you don't need much; `expr = c x1 - c x2; expr//Simplify` will do.

Comment: @FredG If you don't know the recommended way (as well as the most general) to solve the problem is based on this approach `Collect[expr,var, h]`. You can apply it for much more involved algebraic expressions not worrying to play around with rules or whatever else. Look at my answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to make it more directly, but you can hack it like this

```
expr = A ( 2x1 + B (y1 + y2) + 2x2);
Collect[ expr, B];
Plus @@ { Simplify[ %[[1]]] , %[[2]]}
```

which gives

```
(*  2 A ( x1 + x2) + A B ( y1 + y2)  *)
```

not too pretty. I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as stated above, I have much more complicated expressions than just that B. I can't Collect each then simplify again and look again to see what to Collect next...

Answer (score 1):

Consider this as an additional rule-based approach:

```
 expr = A (2 x1 + B (y1 + y2) + 2 x2);
(expr /. {x1 -> X - x2, y1 -> Y - y2} // Simplify) /. {X -> (x1 + x2),
   Y -> (y1 + y2)}
```

yielding the answer: `A (2 (x1 + x2) + B (y1 + y2))`